# Shortcut keys not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I re-enable some of keys that are supposed to light up my keyboard, raise lower volume etc?

I have already gone through msconfig, and have selected all programs that have Asus as the manufacturer, same with the services.

I have an Asus G60.

**Note:** Some of the other shortcuts, like raising and lowering the screen brightness work, but there is no icon that is displayed to show that it is happening. Also, I can raise/lower the keyboard brightness before logging in but not after.

Comment: I can't say why it's not working when you log in, but the [Asus Utility and Bloatware Guide](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/380681-asus-utility-bloatware-guide.html) may help narrow down the culprit.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing [ATK Hotkey](http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=84571&t=0&i=1) fixed the problem.